# How I can get chunked transfer coding data by HTTPChunkedStreamBuf?

Tags: poco-libraries

Good day!

I try to read HTTP message bodies in chunked transfer coding from IP camera (event notification). When I send request, IP camera  respond to me.

But when I try to check data in buffer 
std::streamsize size1 = chunkStreamBuffer.in_avail();

I can see that size1 is 0. Data in buffer is absent.

I've checked data transfer by Wireshark and can see than IP camera send chunked data for me. I've checked data transfer by browser and can see that transfer is OK (I send the same URI in my application and in browser). Source code is below.

Question - how I can get chunked data by POCO library ?

PS. Thank you for your help.

```
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPIOStream.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
.....
#include "Poco/Net/..." //other POCO header

HTTPClientSession pSession;
HTTPBasicCredentials pCredentials;
HTTPRequest pRequest;
HTTPResponse pResponse;

pSession.setHost(host); 
pCredentials.setUsername(username); 
pCredentials.setPassword(password); 

pRequest.setMethod(HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET); 
pRequest.setVersion(HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
pRequest.setURI(stringURI);

pRequest.setKeepAlive(true);
pSession.setKeepAlive(true);

pCredentials.authenticate(pRequest);

pSession.sendRequest(pRequest);

pHTTPStatus = pResponse.getStatus();
if (pHTTPStatus == HTTPResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED)  
{
  pRequest.set("Authorization", AuthorizationString);

  pRequest.setKeepAlive(true);
  pSession.setKeepAlive(true);
  pRequest.set("Accept", "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
  pRequest.set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

  pSession.sendRequest(pRequest);

  std::istream& rs = pSession.receiveResponse(pResponse); 

  pHTTPStatus = pResponse.getStatus();
  if (pHTTPStatus == HTTPResponse::HTTP_OK)  
  {
    Poco::Net::HTTPChunkedStreamBuf chunkStreamBuffer(pSession, ios_base::in);
    chunkStreamBuffer.pubsetbuf( bufResponse, sizeof(bufResponse) );
    //chunkStreamBuffer.pubseekpos(0);

    std::string strReason = pResponse.getReason(); //in my case strReason is OK
    bool keepAlive = pResponse.getKeepAlive(); // is my case keepAlive is true
    std::string text = pResponse.get("Connection");

    chunkStreamBuffer.pubsync();
    std::streamsize size1 = chunkStreamBuffer.in_avail();
    chunkStreamBuffer.sgetn( bufResponse, size1 );
    bufResponse[size1]=0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession class internally handles chunked transfer encoding in a response, so there's nothing special to do here. Just read from the response stream. Also, it's sufficient to call setKeepAlive(true) on the session. One thing though, you have to handle deflate or gzip encoding yourself:

```
if (pResponse->get("Content-Encoding", "") == "gzip")
{
    Poco::InflatingInputStream inflater(rs, Poco::InflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
    // read from inflater
}
else
{
    // read from rs
}
```

Normally it's sufficient to handle gzip content-encoding only, as deflate may have some compatibility issues.

Comment: Not sure this answers the original question.  The user wants to receive the data a chunk at a time, because each chunk has a semantic meaning (e.g., a single camera frame).   POCO's input stream just concatenates the chunks together in a single byte stream so there's no way to tell where the chunk boundaries are.  Is there a way to specifically read a chunk at a time?